# How to merge two maps of sensitive data in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have a module which contains an output marked as sensitive. This is then getting injected into another module where it merges the contents of that output with another map of sensitive data. For example:

```
  module "first_module" {
    output "my_secrets" {
      description  = "test"
      sensitive    = true
      value        = {
        "super_secret" = {
          username = "foo"
          password = "bar"
        }
      }
    }
  }

  module "second_module" {
    secrets = merge(module.first_module.my_secrets,
      {
        "something_else" = {
          value = "test"
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

The error I receive when terraform apply is run is:

```
for_each = var.secrets
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.secrets has a sensitive value
│ 
│ Sensitive values, or values derived from sensitive values, cannot be used
│ as for_each arguments. If used, the sensitive value could be exposed as a
│ resource instance key.
```

After doing some research the only workaround I have found is to wrap the merge in `nonsensitive` to flag it as such but I'm hoping there's a better solution which makes more sense for handling senstive data.

Comment: There is no better way.

Comment: https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/4538432032787-Variable-has-a-sensitive-value-and-cannot-be-used-as-for-each-arguments - looks like there are two options